# Styling GridView Header based on Bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

ASP.NET Web Forms Project. Using GridView and using Bootstrap CSS Class "table table-striped".  I would like to create a class of colors for the table header. For example:

```
.MyHeader {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
```

I want to set the CSS Class of the grid view as:
"table table-striped MyHeader"

If I use GridView header style, the color rule applies but the background-color is overwritten by the Bootstrap.css.  Here is how Bootstrap.css sets the background color:

```
.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > td, .table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > th {
    background-color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: C1pher, thank you for editing my post. I still don't know how to make the code look like code :(.

Comment: Have you tried with !important for background-color in .MyHeader?

Comment: @tkestowicz No. I don't know how to use !important but will look it up.  Thank you.

Comment: As far as I remember CSS styles which are more specific are the most important. That's why you have to mark importance explicitly.

Comment: @tkestowicz Important didn't make a difference. But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: According to this:
  
`The !important value appended a CSS property value is an automatic win. It overrides even inline styles from the markup. The only way an !important value can be overridden is with another !important rule declared later in the CSS and with equal or great specificity value otherwise.`
  
Is has to work. Are you sure that you have refreshed the page correctly (with CTRL+F5)?

Comment: @tkestowicz  Yes, I am sure that I set the !important and refreshed correctly. My solution will be to do away with Boostrap CSS for the GridView and create my own. I already tried a test of defining my own rules for the gridview table, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug. Right click on the table select COPY CSS PATH like: [image]

i think you can use copied path in the css.